# TPC-DS data generation

Tags: database-recommendation, benchmark

Is there a way to generate TPC-DS/TPC-H data using Normal Distribution, i.e., is there a way to specify the distribution type while generating TPC-DS/TPC-H?

EDIT : I believe there is an option for TPC-H DBGEN. I would like to know if there is a similar one for TPC-DS DSGEN.

Thanks!